# Serial.print attatch a variable unintended

Tags: c, printing, arduino, serial-port, at-command

I'm programming an Arduino UNO with a SIM7600CE LTE Shield. I want to track the position and get the Received Signal Strength Indication. I can communicate with the shield and it works great. Now I want to transform the answers to my wanted values. Here is my Code:

```
void readRSSI(void){
  char RecMessage[200]="0";
  char s_RSSI[2]="0";
  char s_BER[2]="0";
  int i_RSSI=0, i_BER=0;
  int i =0;
  char * pch;
  bool answer=false;
  //while(myserial.available() == 0);
  myserial.write("AT+csq\r");
      do{
        if(myserial.available() > 0){
          RecMessage[i]=myserial.read();
          i++;
          if (strstr(RecMessage, "OK") != NULL){
            answer = true;
          }
        }
      } while (!answer);
      myserial.flush();
      if(answer){
        pch = strstr(RecMessage,",");
        int posi = pch - RecMessage;
        s_RSSI[0]=RecMessage[posi-2];
        s_RSSI[1]=RecMessage[posi-1];
        s_BER[0]=RecMessage[posi+1];
        s_BER[1]=RecMessage[posi+2];
        i_RSSI=atoi(s_RSSI);
        i_BER=atoi(s_BER);
      }
      Serial.flush();
      
      Serial.println("RSSI Info:");
     // Serial.println(RecMessage);
      Serial.print("Received Signal Strength Indication: ");
      Serial.print(i_RSSI);
      Serial.print(" and Channel Bit Error Rate: ");
      Serial.println(i_BER);
      Serial.flush();
      return;
}
```

The RecMessage is something like this:

```
AT+csq

+CSQ: 31,99

OK
```

So the Code basicly looks where the `','` is and take the left and the right numbers of it. It kinda works well, but somehow my output is this:

```
12:03:51.068 -> RSSI Info:

12:03:51.114 -> Received Signal Strength Indication: 31 and Channel Bit Error Rate: 9931
```

But thats not what it should be ... somehow it put's the i_RSSI at the end of the i_BER. The best Part is, if I comment out the `Serial.print(i_RSSI);`, it works right, the Serial shows just `99`. Can somebody explain what I am missing?.

I'm using the Arduino IDE 1.8.19.

Comment: In C and C++, strings are nul-terminated character sequences. Your arrays `s_RSSI[2]` and `s_BER[2]` can only hold strings of length 1, i.e a 2-digit number will not be terminated properly. As a result, `atoi` will see `"3391"` and it is just by accident that there is a 0 byte nearby.

Comment: BTW: Arduino uses C++, not C. In C these calls to `Serial.print` would not be legal with different parameter types.

Comment: Ahhh yes, that's it!

Comment: Could you please let me know does  SIM7600CE works for Indian networks?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming UART communication with AT commands and similar; then string null terminators are never sent on the bus, but instead CR and/or LF are used as delimiters. So you need to append null terminators manually on things you pick up from the bus. And this must be done *before* you call C standard lib functions like `strstr` or `strlen` which assume that you pass them a null terminated string.